# Export excel chart as picture (through automation)

Tags: matlab, vba, excel, com

I am trying to get a handle on an excel graph and save it through MATLAB.

So far I have managed to cycle through sheets and get a handle on the graph object but I can't save it.
Does anyone know how to export the object as a `jpg` or `png` or other graphic format?

I tried the code below using the `SaveAs` method but it doesn't work

```
Workbook = Workbooks.Open(['file.name]);
Sheets = Workbook.Sheets;
for i = 1:Sheets.Count
    Activesheet = get(Sheets, 'Item',i);
    for j = 1:Activesheet.ChartObjects.Count
        obj = Activesheet.ChartObjects(j);
        obj.SaveAs('asfasfa.jpg')

    end
end
```

Comment: Just edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The excel `Chart` objects have an `Export` method.

Microsoft documentation : [Chart.Export Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198129.aspx)

---

For the example, I created a simple excel file (named `test_save_chart.xlsx`) with a chart in the first sheet. To export this chart as a `PNG` picture is pretty straightforward:

```matlab
xfile = 'test_save_chart.xlsx' ;
exl = actxserver('excel.application');                  %// Create a COM server
exlFile    = exl.Workbooks.Open( [pwd '\' xfile] );     %'// Open the file

chartobj = exlFile.Sheets.Item('Sheet1').ChartObjects(1) ;                %// get a handle to the chart object
chartobj.Chart.Export('C:\TEMP\StackExchange\testChartExport.png','PNG')  %// export to PNG
```

---

In your case, inside your loop, it is as simple as:

```matlab
chartobj = Activesheet.ChartObjects(j) ;
chartobj.Chart.Export('your_filename_here.png','PNG')
```

---

Since you are doing that in a loop, you will have to generate the file name dynamically (otherwise you are going to overwrite the same file over and over again).

Note that `png` format is recommended over `jpg`, specially for "line art" style of picture like excel chart produce.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you so much. Worked like a charm